# remove empty <p> tags from wordpress shortcodes via a php functon

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

Looking for a php function (non-jQuery or wpautop modification) approach to remove `<p></p>` from within wordpress.

I tried this but it does not work:

```
        function cleanup_shortcode_fix($content) {   
          $array = array (
            '<p>[' => '[', 
            ']</p>' => ']', 
            ']<br />' => ']',
            ']<br>' => ']'
          );
          $content = strtr($content, $array);
            return $content;
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix');
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have spaces or whitespace (\n, etc) in the content beween the bracket and the tags?

Comment: Wouldn't the editor be surprised when his paragraph starting with a bracket will suddenly be a broken paragraph..

Comment: @DamienOvereem: An implementation of [`has_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) would fix that.

Comment: Just wanted to note that the above code worked for me if I add 10 priority to the end of the add_filter, like `add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix',10,1);`

Answer (score 15):

Try inserting this code in your `functions.php` file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop', 99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop', 100 );
```

[image]

Comment: I have also tried this solution, but I found the other question, it generated P tags in another places.

Comment: Works great! I wasn't sure where to put the code though so I tested it and added a screenshot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

`add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix', 10);`

I found that it works if you specify 10 as the priority; no other number will work.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I solved this today and thought I'd share.

In my case, I basically want to remove all the poorly formatted `<p>` and `<br>` tags, but then you want to add them back in correctly so that the text in the shortcode gets formatted correctly.

```
/*
 * Half column shortcode
 */
    function custom_shortcode_half_column( $atts, $content = '') {
        $content = custom_filter_shortcode_text($content);
        return '<div class="half-column">'. $content .'</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'half-column', 'custom_shortcode_half_column' );


/*
 * Utility function to deal with the way WordPress auto formats text in a shortcode.
 */
    function custom_filter_shortcode_text($text = '') {
        // Replace all the poorly formatted P tags that WP adds by default.
        $tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
        $text = str_replace($tags, "\n", $text);

        // Remove any BR tags
        $tags = array("<br>", "<br/>", "<br />");
        $text = str_replace($tags, "", $text);

        // Add back in the P and BR tags again, remove empty ones
        return apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    }
```

This really should be the default way WordPress parses the shortcode $content parameter in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a regex could work:

```
$string=preg_replace_('/<p>\s*</p>/', '', $string);
```

That should replace any `<p></p>` with nothing or just whitespaces in it to nothing, thus removing them.

When applying regex to HTML code it's a good idea to remove the `\r\n` of the HTML first, since they stop the regex from working.

Comment: this is not helpful, because remove all p tag in content, and sometimes p tag has style

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the priority of the filter.

This should work

```
add_filter('the_content', 'cleanup_shortcode_fix', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove

Tag enter

```
<?php echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

instead of  the_content()

Answer (score -4):

What you need is a mix of jquery and php... that is the only working way
that i found to be working really well. i have tutorial on my site but
in order to keep stuff inhouse here goes

**The jQuery:**
*include this in some JS file you already enqueue*

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('div#removep > p').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
    })
    .remove()
})
```

**A shortcode you can later use:**
*in your functions.php or included file*

```
function sght_removep( $atts, $content = null ) {return '<div id="removep">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';}
add_shortcode('removep', 'sght_removep');
```

**Now you can wrap specific stuff like this:**

```
[removep]
Some text i write directly in wordpress wysiwyg
<p></p> <-- this would get removed
[/removep]
```

This solution requires some know how but it works!
Hope this helps...

Comment: This is quite possibly the worst answer I've ever seen on SO. It doesn't answer the question, as the OP explicitly said not jQuery and it is a terrible solution, because you should never fix bad markup in Javascript, especially when you have the opportunity to fix it in PHP before it ever gets served.

Comment: You are wrong! in many cases you dont want to to do a global fix but a simple targeted fix while writing a post! you should not change WP entire output just to fix a coulumn structure or other elements you want to target. In many cases you dont have "bad markup" - you just want to target a specific element... (btw: thanks for the drama).

Comment: Who said anything about a global fix? You might just need to fix one shortcode or a few, I get that. And I don't see a perfect answer on this page. But a crappy JS hack is not the answer. WP is blighted by far too much "I just did this crappy hack and it works for me" code suggestions already.

Comment: This is a gr8 solution... the problam of un-desired P tags in shortcodes and other places would apear again & again... in must cases its ok - its even gr8 sometimes and thats why shutting it off (which is easy) isnt the best solution for everyone! but sometimes it will bother and so a small shortcode is gr8 way to fix specific issues - furthermore i see no problam in using jQuery to customize elements and how they aprear. this is common in today web-design world.